# How to make two images one above each other in android

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, overlap

In My application I have one big imageview 'A' and six small imageviews s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,intially  set the all imageviews with some drawbles.

when  drag the small images(s1,s2 etc) and drop on the big imageview 'A' then it is replacing with corresponding image.
for example lets say Imageview A have BAT Image and imageview s1 have the BALL Image when  drag the BALL image onto BAT Image then the BAT Image is replacing with BALL Image.

MY Requirement is that when i drag the BALL Image onto the BAT Image then the BAT image should be there and the BALL Image should be overlap(one above each other).so BAT and BALL images should be there on imageview A.

Comment: You can create this using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. The order of the imageviews will be lastly inserted will be shown above.

eg:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/A"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/bat"
                 />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/s1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ball"
                 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml code

```
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1" 
 android:orientation="vertical"> 
  <!-- Add   image A --> 

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" 
  android:layout_width="800dp" 
  android:layout_height="400dp"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:src="@drawable/image1" /> 

   <!-- Add smaller image--> 

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2" 
  android:layout_width="400dp"
  android:layout_height="200dp" 
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1" 
  android:src="@drawable/image2" />     
</RelativeLayout>
```

The output will look like below

[image: output image]

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout.
For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:src="@drawable/prescription_not_attached"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:src="@drawable/home_measure"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

Replace my Images with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a FrameLayout, using Linear will not allow overlapping...

```
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
ImageView bat = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bat);
ImageView ball = new ImageView(this);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
i.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); 
frame.addView(bat);
frame.addView(ball);
```